# Sum of two multinomial distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm struggling with a question about combining two multinomial distributions. My background in probability theory is pretty weak, so I think I might be missing something simple here. I'm supposed to find the distribution of $X_1 + X_2$.
There are $n$ independent trials. Each trial results in one of $r$ outcomes $(1, 2, \dots, r)$. For each trial, outcome $i$ occurs with probability $p_i$. Let $X_i$ be the number of trials resulting in outcome $i$. Then
$(X_1, X_2, \dots , X_r)$ has the multinomial distribution.
In addition to finding the distribution of $X_1 + X_2$, I also need to compute variance of $X_1+X_2$ and $\operatorname{cov}(X_1,X_2)$.

I'd appreciate if somebody could help dumb this down for me. I made the mistake of overestimating my own background in probability theory before I took this class, so now I'm totally lost.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- Show that the distribution of $X_1+X_2$ is a particular binomial distribution. (Define a "success" as "either outcome 1 or outcome 2 occurs.") This will also allow you to find the variance of $X_1 + X_2$.
- To find the covariance, use the fact that $\text{Var}(X_1+X_2) = \text{Var}(X_1) + \text{Var}(X_2) + 2 \text{Cov}(X_1, X_2)$.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! I think this helps me with the next step, but I'm still struggling with the first step of figuring out what the distribution of X1 + X2 actually is.

Comment: @Shan $X_1+X_2$ is the number of "successes" in $n$ trials, if you define "success" in a certain way. This is how the binomial distribution is defined.

Answer (score 0):

As is so often the case, working with a specific numeric example will help you understand what is going on in the general case.

Suppose $r = 5$ and we have $$(p_1, p_2, p_3, p_4, p_5) = (0.1, 0.15, 0.3, 0.2, 0.25).$$  The random vector $(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5)$ follows a multinomial distribution with probability mass function $$\Pr\left[\bigcap_{i=1}^5 X_i = x_i\right] = \binom{n}{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5} \prod_{i=1}^5 p_i^{x_i}.$$  So for example, if $n = 11$, we have $$\Pr[(X_1, X_2, X_3, X_4, X_5) = (1, 1, 4, 2, 3)] = \frac{11!}{1! 1! 4! 2! 3!} (0.1)^1 (0.15)^1 (0.3)^4 (0.2)^2 (0.25)^3 = \frac{168399}{1600000}.$$
Now, what is the meaning of the random variable $X_1 + X_2$ in the above example?  Suppose we let $Y = X_1 + X_2$.  Then the corresponding outcome in our example is $Y = 2$, since we asked for $X_1 = X_2 = 1$.  But clearly $(1, 1, 4, 2, 3)$ is not the only outcome for which $Y = 2$; we also have outcomes like $(1, 1, 0, 0, 9)$, or $(2, 0, 4, 2, 3)$, etc.  So if I asked for $\Pr[Y = 2]$, how would we calculate it?  We note that if $Y = 2$, then $X_3 + X_4 + X_5 = n - 2$, because the total sum is always $n$.  If we continue with the example above with $n = 11$, what you are looking for are those outcomes where we observe exactly two occurrences among the $X_1, X_2$ categories, and nine occurrences among the other categories.  So $Y$ is a binomial random variable with probability mass function $$\Pr[Y = y] = \binom{n}{y} \theta^y (1-\theta)^{n-y},$$ where $\theta$ is the probability of getting an observation in either $X_1$ or $X_2$.  Since these are mutually exclusive, we have $\theta = p_1 + p_2 = 0.25$, hence $$\Pr[Y = 2] = \binom{11}{2} (0.25)^2 (0.75)^9 = \frac{1082565}{4194304}.$$

Now that we have worked out a specific example, how would you reason in the general case?